# Dynamically insert and execute a script resource

Tags: javascript

Hope I can explain this properly. We are currently inserting this external JS in our HTML:

```
<script src="https://NotOurDomain.com/SomeScript.js"></script>
```

The code in this script resource is something like this:

```
var callbackUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
var token = encodeURIComponent('eidoasjdiojancoxjnegkjasd');
var url = 'https://NotOurDomain.com/path?token=' + token + '&callbackUrl=' + callbackUrl;

document.open();
document.write('<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
document.close();
```

This all works fine, but now I need to insert this dynamically. Problem is, I can't just copy the code in this script resource because the "token" part changes periodically.

How can I get this to work? Is it possible to load https://NotOurDomain.com/SomeScript.js as a string and parse out the token so that I could create and insert an iframe with the correct URL? Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

This obviously does not work because a script include will only execute on load:

```
jQuery('#someDiv').append('<script src="https://NotOurDomain.com/SomeScript.js"></script>');
```

But is there some way to get it to "eval" after inserting?

Comment: Just insert the token as a data attribute or a variable in a script tag, and get it with your script ?

Comment: We don't have control over the token or their javascript. It's all on a 3rd party server. The only thing we can do is access it with the script tag: <script src="https://NotOurDomain.com/SomeScript.js"></script>